# Installing Xubuntu on Asus Transformer T101HA-GR043T

Tags: boot, xubuntu, asus

I have an Asus Transformer T101HA-GR043T, a netbook withous USB ports. I want to erase the Windows version installed on it (I think is either Windows 8.1 or Windows 10) and install Xubuntu as main and only operating system. I have tried using Unetbootin from the boot screen but it doesn't work, it gives me a console-like screen when I select Unetbootin and nothing more. There is another method that I can use in order to install Xubuntu?

Comment: does the efi firmware allow you to turn off secure boot and select OS to boot?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with installing any Linux distro in a T101HA-GR043T. It runs a very Linux-unfriendly CPU ("Bay Trail") for which a special ISO is needed (from Linuxium) and even so some hardware will not work, most notably the audio. @ravery Bay Trail/Cherry Trail firmware does not have the option to turn off Secure Boot (and has no CSM/Legacy mode either). Bottom line: This entry level products were designed to run Windows 8 or newer only.

Comment: @MichaelBay Well...that sucks...

Comment: "Linux on Asus T100" is an offshoot of a long-established forum that was on Google Groups until the latter closed down.  It is now a Facebook group at:  https://www.facebook.com/groups/381498159345464/.  It is quite likely that someone on that group will be using your specific model of the T100 and will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I have same model, I spend so much time with installing different linux versions and here are the results:

Ubuntu - 17.10 works great, also audio with newest kernel. Only bad is brightness (And card reader I think). Brightness can't set up (still max).

Lightweight desktop environments(XFCE-Xubuntu, Cinnamon-mint, LXDE, etc...) work with more mistakes(mainly rotation).

Android x86 - works very fast, smooth, great battery condition and it seems ideal for this tablet. But! I don't find any way how to make rotation and graphic card work :(.

It is easy to try. Create live USBe from ISO in Linux Mint with its default livelinux-create app (I don't remember the name). It will work.